# Mathematica gives weird solution to $y=xy'+y'$

Tags: differential-equations

So I am practicing solving differential equations using Mathematica, and I will usually get an answer that I can easily verify. (as in I solve the differential equations myself and then check with Mathematica) Now, I wanted to try solving $y=xy'+y'$ using Mathematica, and I got a really weird answer when I tried to solve it. This is what Mathematica is giving me:$$\left\{\left\{y\to\text{Function}\left[\{x\},e^xc_1+e^x\int_1^x-e^{-K[1]}xy'[K[1]]dK[1]\right]\right\}\right\}$$ I feel like the correct solution would be as follows:$$\begin{align}y=&\,xy'+y'\\\implies y=&\,y'(x+1)\\y=&\,\dfrac{dy}{dx}(x+1)\\\dfrac{dy}y=&\dfrac{dx}{x+1}\\\int\dfrac{dy}y=&\int\dfrac{dx}{x+1}\\\gets\ln|y|+c_0=&\ln|x+1|+c_1\\\color{red}e^{\ln|y|+c_0}=&\color{red}e^{\ln|x+1|+c_1}\\ye^{c_0}=&(x+1)e^{c_1}\\y(x)=&(x+1)\dfrac{e^{c_0}}{e^{c_1}}\\=&(x+1)\exp(c_2)\quad c_0+c_1=c_2\end{align}$$which could be further simplified as$$y(x)=(x+1)c_3$$because $\exp(c_2)$ is another constant. This is also what [Wolfram Alpha gives](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=y%3Dxy%27%2By%27).

My code so far:

```
eqn=y[x]==xy'[x]+y'[x]
DSolve[eqn,y,x]
```

So my question is:

#### Why is this the result that Mathematica is giving me?

My current code does perfectly fine with differential equations such as $y'y+y'=\ln(y)$, $y'=y$ (even with the boundary condition $y(0)=\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is some number), so I don't know what the problem could be here.

Comment: `DSolve[y[x] == x y'[x] + y'[x], y[x], x]`

Comment: @Syed That gives `{}` as the output, so idk how that would help

Comment: Or in your case, add a space: `eqn = y[x] == x y'[x] + y'[x];
DSolve[eqn, y, x]`. Use ```Clear["Global`*"]``` to clear variables.

Comment: @Syed Output is now `TerminatedEvaluation[RecursionLimit]` (I did copy/paste your comment in directly if that makes sense) edit: it seems you edited it so I'll try again

Comment: Try restarting Mathematica

Comment: @Syed oh okay it gives the correct answer now wonder what was happening

Comment: Perhaps you used `=` when you meant `==` and accidently defined something

Comment: One should always pay attention to the color of variable, when a variable is "empty", it'll be blue, but when something is stored in it, it'll be black.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
eqn = y[x] == x y'[x] + y'[x];

DSolve[eqn, y, x]
```

Save your notebook, close it, reopen it, run it.

[image]